# Show That a Lift Always Exists

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I've been considering this problem:  Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and that $H_1(X)$ is a finite group of odd order.  Show that if $p:\tilde{Y}\rightarrow Y$ is a covering space of index $2$, then any map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ can be lifted to a map $\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow \tilde{Y}$ so that $p\circ \tilde{f}=f$.

It is easy to show that any index $2$ subgroup contains all elements of odd order.  So, if $\gamma\in\pi_1(X)$ has odd order, then $f_*(\gamma)\in p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{Y}))$.  So, I'm thinking that it might be if $H_1(X)$ is finite of odd order, $\pi_1(X)$ must have all elements of odd order.  Is that so?  Or, is there another way to do this problem?

Comment: No, that's not true. $\pi_1$ can be a finite perfect group (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group), such as a finite simple group, which will in general have elements of even order, and in this case $H_1$ is even trivial. A historically important explicit example, motivating the importance of the simply connected hypothesis in the Poincare conjecture, is the Poincare dodecahedral space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere).

Comment: Try using the fact that any index $2$ subgroup is normal.